# Can a USB port Masquarade as a Virtual USB Stick?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, ubuntu-16.04

We have an interesting scenario.

We are currently programing a Linux workstation with our own firmware; the station boots from USB stick and loads firmware from the stick.

There is also an adjacent test station to run some testing.  We are trying to figure out if there is a way to connect the test station to the Linux workstation (USB port to USB port); and have the Linux workstation believe instead of being connected to the Test Station (basically another workstation); that it is connected to a USB stick and boot from there?

This would allow us to remove the USB stick from the equation; basically plugging in a cable from the test station; and when we need to update the firmware, we would not have to replace the stick, just update data on the workstation.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Dan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 'not possible'; after extensive research, there is no efficient way to accomplish this.